# Deep text file processing

Tags: java

When dealing with text files in java, is there any way to achieve this results:

Assuming that my text file contains the data below(User number, first name, last name, username, user type)

```
Num010101   James   Jackson   JJ123   Normal_User
```

Now I have another file that contains login info (user, password)

```
JJ123   abc
```

When the the user logs in to the system I'd like to check the first file using .contains(username), now if the username is found within a line then I want to print the first and last name which are separated by a tab character.

I prefer not to use mapping here I want to print the line without the first, third and forth value.

In c++ I normally do it using the map library or iterator (for example < First_value, Second_Value > and i->first , i->second) but since I'm new to java I am kind of stuck.

I'd like to skip the first, third and forth value in printing, that is what I am looking for not mapping.

Comment: Without meaning to sound condescending, is there a reason why you're not using a relational database?

Comment: I solved this problem myself so simply by using Replace. I'm always looking for the fastest and easiest way to deal with problems, of course split and hashmap would probably give me the same result but what I found was so easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at HashMap

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: The program only checks if a line contains the username then I don't know how many values I might have in text file but I know that the last name is behind the username and the first name behind the last name. I looked at some hashmap examples but I don't think I can do it using hashmap. (Maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: You will need to load the text file in HaspMap (Which means you need to parse the file). HashMap is collection of key, value pair. You can have username as key. Then by simply using *get* method you can get the value for that username which can be what ever you have stored there

Comment: I am looking for way to print the file without the first, third and forth value (assuming that I have four values) , this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can read the line and using split function of String create the array of all value and use that accordingly

Comment: If you are just looking for help dealing with Strings read from a file, have a look at the StrigUtils API: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html  It has various split/find methods that could potentially help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would create a class for containing the information about the person:

```
public class Person{
    String number, first, last, username, type;
}
```

Then you would parse the file to create instances of `Person` for each line in the file. You can use `String.split()` for this or guava's `Splitter`.

Next I would map the set of `Persons` in a `Map<String, Person>` where the key is the username.

You could implement the `toString` method in `Person` to return the first / last names formatted however you like.